# Send data from javascript to html and fetch with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery-select2

ok, i don't know if this is the proper way of doing this. If not, please give me an example on how to do it. How do i fetch the data in the JS and send it to html?

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var choosenYear = $('#choose_year');
$("#choose_year").select2({
    data: [{
        id: 0,
        text: '2015'
    }, {
        id: 1,
        text: '2014'
    }],
    val: ["0"]
}).select2('val', 0);

// Start Change
$(choosenYear).change(function() {
    var choosenYear = $(choosenYear).select2('data').id;
    $('#choosen_year').val(choosenYear);
 }); //Change
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline well col-md-8" id="form-choose_usr" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
//This is what i POST
<div>
  <input type='hidden' class='col-md-4' id='choose_usr_email' name='choose_usr_email'>
 </div>
 <!-- Select2 choose_year -->
 <div>
 <input type='hidden' class='col-md-2' id='choose_year' name='choose_year'>
 </div>
 <!-- Select2 choose_month -->
 <div>
<input type='hidden' id='choosen_year' name='choosen_year'>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" value="Hämta" />
```

**PHP**

```
//And this is how i fetch it
$posted_choosen_year = $_POST['choosen_year'];
echo $posted_choosen_year;
```

Comment: In php you now can output the Variable like `echo "Chosen year: " . $posted_chosen_year;` if the js syntax is right and your INPUT is surrounded by a form tag that points to your php.

Comment: This i know, but the js is incorrect!?

Comment: It depends on what you are exactly doing in your JS. It lookes like you have a selectbox, dropdown list or something? Or where does the data for the chosen year come from?

Comment: @Eddi I use Select2 dropdown menu. The shown options is: 2015 and 2014, it is listed in the JS.

Comment: What exactly is the error you get? The way looks good.

Comment: @Daniel My variable is empty, nothing is echo'ed

Comment: plz change `echo $posted_choosen_year;` to `var_dump( $posted_choosen_year);` and post the result

Comment: Well first of all you use the same variable choosenYear everytime, though they are differently (it seems so). Are you able to distinct this and change the variables name, so we can see which variable is actually doing what?

Comment: try print_r($_POST), this will  let you see all your post data.. next part.. turn on PHP errors... You might have a syntax error or something.. Sounds like basic debugging here

Comment: @Daniel string(0) ""

Comment: plz select 2015 and post result

Comment: @Daniel Still: string(0) ""

Comment: @Mayhem Array ( [choose_usr_email] => 5 [choose_year] => 0 [choose_month] => 02 [choosen_usr_email] => bla@bla.com[choosen_year] => )

Comment: choosen_year is sending a blank value, so try changing it from hidden to text so you can watch the value is for it.. The string "" means it never has had a value set. try doing an alert on "$(choosenYear).select2('data').id" in the first line of your change event

Comment: added more from form...

Comment: will have answer in a few minutes, bare with me.. short answer... "$(choosenYear).select2('data').id" is not a valid object.. it returns nothing.. just playing around with the select2 plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery change function is not the propper event:

```
$("#choosenYear").on("select2:select", function (e) { do stuff here... });
```

will do. See http://select2.github.io/examples.html under "EVENTS" for more. There are also running samples that will provide how to use this thing.

I corrected your fiddle and got it running by this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function log(text) {
        $('#chosen_year').append(text + '<br>');
    }

$('#choose_year').select2()
    .on("change", function(e) {
        log(this.value);
    }) 
});
```

Comment: I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/8byz7n25/  It works on my server, but in the fiddle it´s says "undefined" ?!

Comment: Thank you, but i can not really find out how to use the "Event" to populate a php variable. Event works with "Div" but not with "Span" or "Input".

Comment: got that runnin, see above. `e.val`, where did you get this from?

Answer (score 0):

Okay,, using this fiddle i just created to test: http://jsfiddle.net/yL6g087x/1/

If shows that object

```
$("#choosenYear").select2("data")
```

Does not exist... so i thought i would consult with the manual.. rtm.. and their example fails.. on two levels.... Their fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/platypusman/xDUUg/

Firstly returns 404 for the js and css files... so i linked in their current ones.. and the example still fails to work.. It looks like the select2 plugin is broken on its current version..

**I could be wrong, but its what i find from their provided example**

Comment: Very strange.. When i use this with a ajax call to get the data it works propertly!

Comment: If you can give me a working example where you can read the value of the selected item.. as in the id, not the text value. then i'll have a quick look and should be able to merge em

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p5ajkdzq/  This code works if you type in a url and fetch data with php

Comment: The fiddle you've pasted above uses ajax and json for the datatype, it does not use a standard data attribute.

Comment: Yes, i know. I use that when fetching the data from mysql threw a back-end PHP script. But it should be simular when storing the data in JS.

Comment: i've been searching and can not see one that uses the data attribute in that way.. there are few examples or SOF examples but none of them work with version 4.. i'm guessing this was an older version, it seems that v4 uses the data attribute as a filter return method only.. So you could make your data array global and then use the data attribute to filter the data array

Comment: ok. I use: select2-3.5.1 I solved the problem by use html values instead of storing them in the js file. Thank you very much for your support!

Answer (score 0):

So, i did't really find out how to solve it. So i changed the code to have static HTML values instead of storing the values in the JS file.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline well col-md-8" id="form-choose_usr" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <select class="col-md-4" id="choose_year" name="choose_year" required>
    <option></option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" value="Hämta" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#choose_year').select2({
    placeholder: 'Välj år..',
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1
  });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$posted_chosen_year = $_POST['choose_year'];
echo $posted_chosen_year;
```